# easiest way to get sha256 of mobile apps

Tags: android, android-studio, sha

Am trying to find a way to get SHA256 of a mobile app,i have search around but i didn't understand some of the things i came across. i tried

```
  MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

 try {
     md.update(toChapter1);
     MessageDigest tc1 = md.clone();
     byte[] toChapter1Digest = tc1.digest();
     md.update(toChapter2);
     ...etc.
 } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
     throw new DigestException("couldn't make digest of partial content");
 }
```

and also if you can explain the concept i will be glad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a Hashing Library at [android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com) and its very easy,simple and just one line of code. can hash MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512.

1.first add this to your gradle and sync

`implementation 'com.github.1AboveAll:Hasher:1.2'`

2. Start hashing...

`Hasher.Companion.hash("Hello",HashType.SHA_1);`

Answer (score 1):

To access APIs in Android from Google API console you need to generate an API Key. This same API key can be used for accessing multiple APIs under the same project. To generate an API key you require, SHA1 fingerprint of your keystore. Keystore is basically a place where the private keys for your app are kept. In simple words its a certificate generated by a user or a program, used for signing an Android app.

In Android, there are two types of keystores. A debug keystore and a release keystore. Debug keystore is generated automatically when the Android SDK is installed or run for the first time. Release keystore has to be generated manually by the user for each application before release. As it requires private information such as name, password etc. To obtain an Android SHA1 fingerprint from your desired keystore.

Comment: i know how to get SHA1, what i need is SHA256